# How to show the retrieved values from local storage in javascript when the browser window of the form is duplicated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I want to get the data in form fields when the browser window is duplicated. I am storing the data in local storage for the below form:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>CRU ID</label>
                        <select name="cru_agent_detail_id" class="form-control select2" id="user_list">
                            <option value="">Select CRU ID</option>
                            @foreach ($users as $user)
                                <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->cru_id }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Agent Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="agent_name" placeholder="Agent Name"
                        readonly>
                </div>
```

The form's CRU ID field is a select box which is populated from database and upon the selection of the menu the name of agent is shown in agent name field. I am storing the values of the above fields in local storage but cannot fetch them in the input fields when the browser window is duplicated. The code I did for it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        /* let id;
        id = localStorage.getItem('cru_id');
        console.log(id) */

        $('#user_list').change(function() {
            cru_id = $('#user_list').find(":selected").text();
            localStorage.setItem('cru_id', cru_id);
            get_cru_id = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('cru_id'));
            console.log(get_cru_id);
            id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'get-user-detail/' + id,
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    let user = response.data
                    $("#agent_name").val(user.name);
                    agent_name = $("#agent_name").val();
                    localStorage.setItem('agent_name', $("#agent_name").val());
                    get_agent_name = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('agent_name'));
                    console.log(get_agent_name);
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

The values are stored in local storage but are not retrieve when the browser window is duplicated.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by "browser window is duplicated." you mean when you open one than a tab from this page?

Comment: so much wrong here I'm sorry to say.. been a while I've seen php on the frontend, and you're really overdoing DOM reads & writes, which costs alot even on smaller apps. you already have the value from the input, use it instead of getting it again every time. but what your problem seems to be here is the reverse handling of json for storage on top of the back and forth fetching of the same data.. which causes you to overwrite the value you're after in the new window before you can fetch it.. good luck my friend

Comment: @CyrusRaoufi when we open this same window in more than one tab

Comment: @zergski its basically laravel blade